# How to truncate data (avoiding page break) in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I have a listing that must fit in a page. Instead of the default page break behaviour, I need iReport to truncate the listing when it goes over the page size. Any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've had omitted that I still need pagination enabled, because I need a sequence of one-page listings, one after another.

I have a group -- breaking pages by costumer -- and each page should have a listing of costumer related items (generated inside the group) that cannot span over more than one page.

When Jasper finds the next costumer, it should break the page and start a new one-page listing.

What I really need, then, is a means of avoiding page breaks inside this group only. Anyone?

Answer (score 4):

Open up the properties of the page in IReport by clicking the root of the report in the `Report Inspector` window and there is a tick box `Ignore Pagination`.

Tick that and should limit your report to one page.

**Edit:**
If you create subreport for your customers you can also select `Ignore Pagination`, which would mean customer would only be one page in size.

Try using a `Break` from `Palette` window either.

Comment: Your answer is perfect for the question I asked, but -- trying to get straight to the point -- I oversimplified it. My fault! See re-edit, please.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, i think you better make a subreport called Customer. The subreport will be "pagination ignored" and so will be limited to one page, while the parent report won't. In that case the parent report (all customers) will call the next customer record and render it in the subreport.